# Hover + click joint action

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hover

I would like to have a menu which on hover gets "active", then on click keeps that active class, even if the mouse leaves, but if not clicked, that active class gets removed.

I've tried several options, but I can't figure out one that works. At the beginning, I had two different functions, but when clicked, the :hover would takeover afterward and removes the active class..

Initial is red. On hover, should move to hovered link/color.
If not clicked, should go back to being red.
If clicked, body class should stay the one that is clicked.

I was thinking of a function that does

```
hover(
change class to hovered item (red/yellow/blue)
)
mouseleaves(
if have been clicked-> do nothing (keep class of hovered item)
if have not been clicked -> revert to initial class
)
```

https://codepen.io/ifeltblankk/pen/BqWyya

```js
  $(document).ready(function() {  
      
      var initialClass = $( "body" ).attr('class');
    
      $('.nav.desktop li').hover(
      
       function(){
             $( "body").removeClass();
             var Hoverclass = $(this).attr('class');
             $( "body" ).addClass(Hoverclass);
         
              $(this).click(function () {
                
                
              });
         },
         function(){
               $( "body").removeClass();
               $( "body" ).addClass(initialClass);
           
              $(this).click(function () {
                  $( "body" ).addClass(initialClass);
              });
         }
     
      
    );
   
    
});
```

```css
ul.nav{
 position:fixed;
  top:20px;
  left:50px;
}

.color{
  width:20px;
  height:20px;
  background-color:grey;
  position:fixed;
  top:0px;
  left:10px;
  display:block;
}

body.red .color{
  background-color:red;
  top:30px;
}

body.blue .color{
  background-color:blue;
  top:50px;
}

body.yellow .color{
  background-color:yellow;
  top:70px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body class="red">

   <div class="color">
      
  </div>
  <ul class="nav desktop">
    <li class="red">
      Red
    </li>
   <li class="blue">
      Blue
    </li>
    <li class="yellow">
      Yellow
    </li>  <br><br>
    <li>
    The idea is <br>
    hover(<br>
    change body class to hovered item (red/yellow/blue)<br>
    )<br>
    mouseleaves(<br>
    if have been clicked-> do nothing (keep class of hovered item)<br>
    if have not been clicked -> revert to initial class<br>
    )</li>  
  </ul>



</body>
```

Comment: The event type will never be mouseleave, as that's not an event you bound to.  Also that if is a sub if of a test against it matching mouseover, so if that is true, the sub if would also never be true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank's to @Josh Bacon's answer, I managed to find a solution.
Thank you all for your help!
https://codepen.io/ifeltblankk/pen/oaZOdJ

So first we hover and add the hover class.
Then we add a trigger that if clicked, $(this) gets a class "clicked".
If it has NOT been clicked -> the body gets back its initial class.
If it has NOT been clicked -> we remove the class clicked, get that Hoverclass, push it to the body and replace the initialClass by the new one.

```js
  $(document).ready(function() {  
      
      var initialClass = $( "body" ).attr('class');
    
      $('.nav.desktop li').hover(
       
       function(){
            var Hoverclass = $(this).attr('class');
             $( "body").removeClass();
             $( "body" ).addClass(Hoverclass); 
         },
         function(){

              $(this).click(function () {
                  $(this).addClass("clicked");
              });
               if (!$(this).hasClass('clicked')) {
                  $( "body").removeClass();
                  $( "body" ).addClass(initialClass);
              }
              if ($(this).hasClass('clicked')) {
                  $(this).removeClass("clicked");  
                  var Hoverclass = $(this).attr('class');
                  $( "body" ).addClass(Hoverclass);
                  $(this).removeClass("clicked");
                  initialClass = $(this).attr('class');
              }
              
         }
     
      
    );
   
    
});
```

```css
ul.nav{
 position:fixed;
  top:20px;
  left:50px;
}

.color{
  width:20px;
  height:20px;
  background-color:grey;
  position:fixed;
  top:0px;
  left:10px;
  display:block;
}

body.red .color{
  background-color:red;
  top:30px;
}

body.blue .color{
  background-color:blue;
  top:50px;
}

body.yellow .color{
  background-color:yellow;
  top:70px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body class="red">

   <div class="color">
      
  </div>
  <ul class="nav desktop">
    <li class="red">
      Red
    </li>
   <li class="blue">
      Blue
    </li>
    <li class="yellow">
      Yellow
    </li>  <br><br>
    
    The idea is <br>
    hover(<br>
    change body class to hovered item (red/yellow/blue)<br>
    )<br>
    mouseleaves(<br>
    if have been clicked-> do nothing (keep class of hovered item)<br>
    if have not been clicked -> revert to initial class<br>
    )
  </ul>



</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

This version of the logic applies an active class on mouse over and removes it on mouse out.  This moves the red around.  Then, if you click the li to (un)select it, it toggles the blue color to show if a row is selected or not.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.nav.desktop li')
    .on('click', function(){
      $(this).toggleClass('clicked');
    })
    .on('mouseenter', function(){
      $(this).addClass('active');
    })
    .on('mouseleave', function(){
      $(this).removeClass('active');
    });
});
```

```css
.active:not(.clicked) {
  background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
}

.clicked {
  background-color:rgb(0, 0, 255);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="nav desktop">
  <li>
    Lien 1
  </li>
  <li>
    Lien 2
  </li>
  <li>
    Lien 3
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I realized I modified my initial code so much your solution does not function. I edited my codepen & post so that it's clearer.

Answer (score 1):

If I interpreted your question right, you just need to store whether the item has been clicked and then add the class of the clicked element to the body.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".nav.desktop li").hover(function() {
    let body = $("body");
    // Clear the classes, then set to the class of the hovered element
    if (body.attr("class").indexOf("clicked") == -1) {
      body.removeClass();
      body.addClass($(this).attr("class"));
    }
  });

  $(".nav.desktop li").click(function() {
    let body = $("body");
    body.removeClass();
    body.addClass("clicked");
    body.addClass($(this).attr("class"));
  });
});
```

The body class will move to the element that's hovered until it's clicked on, and then will lock that state to the clicked element until it's clicked again,  and will then go to the clicked class.

https://codepen.io/Cr1spyBacon8r/pen/wYJKKQ

Comment: that's great, but it should also be sensitive to hover afterthat!

Comment: Thanks to your answer, I managed to find a solution! 
https://codepen.io/ifeltblankk/pen/oaZOdJ

Answer (score 0):

The way to know if the element was clicked or not in your case is by seeing the background color, if the background-color is blue ("rgb(0, 0, 255)") then the element is clicked and we don't have to do nothing, if it different then we set it to blue. If you don't want to use the background color, I guess you can use a class, attribute or a variable with some key-value items.

Just like this:

```js
   $(document).ready(function() {  
   
$('.nav.desktop li').on('mouseleave mouseover click', function(event) {
          if(event.type == 'click') {
              $(this).css("background-color","blue");

          }
          else if(event.type == 'mouseover') {

              if($(this).css("background-color") != "rgb(0, 0, 255)")
              {
                  $(this).css("background-color","red");
              }
              
          }
          else if(event.type == 'mouseleave') {
              if($(this).css("background-color") != "rgb(0, 0, 255)")
              {
                  $(this).css("background-color","");
              }
                  
              }

          
      });
      
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="nav desktop">
  <li>
    Lien 1
  </li>
  <li>
    Lien 2
  </li>
  <li>
    Lien 3
  </li>    
</ul>
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your anwser, however, the link stays red when the mouse leaves.., it does not go back to none. In my original code, it's a class, but for demonstration purpose, i thought it would be easier to be background colors.

Comment: I am sorry @Dikeneko take a look at the edited snippet, you just had to correct the if of mouseleave and bind that event to the DOM element.

Comment: I'm sorry, I realized I modified my initial code so much your solution does not function. I edited my codepen & post so that it's clearer.